# How to do hammered bracelet

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I've have been stuck for a few days now, i struggle to do hammered bracelet.

Let me show you what i am aiming to do

[image]

It doesn't seem hard and i think it's not, so i was trying to do it in luxcore with voronoi bump node, but it doesn't work cuz i think i don't have enough vertical verticles on my torus mesh (6.4M major radius and 0.06m minor radius, it's 6,4cm and 6 mm IRL) i have maxed out 256 and 256 and try to sculpt but it looks bad

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend sculpting these dents by hand. Your voronoi/bump approach seems more promising. Here's my node setup (the Sphere is just for material preview):

[image]

With the *Color Ramp* node, you can control how much of the darkest and brightest areas of your voronoi bump map will be applied to the material. It's very useful. Also, you may need to "squeeze" the Z Scale in the Texture Mapping node until you get the desired look.